# Should the lens cover / lens cap be on the camera while inside a dry box / dry cabinet?

Tags: maintenance, lens-cap, dry-box, dry-cabinet

Usually, we keep the lens cover / lens cap on the camera if we are not using the camera and we remove the lens cover / lens cap off the camera when we are taking picture.

So, if we put the camera inside a dry box / dry cabinet (to prevent fungi / mold), do we need to keep the lens cover / lens cap on the camera?

If the lens cover / lens cap is on the camera while the camera is inside a dry box / dry cabinet, will it hinder the effectiveness of the dry box / dry cabinet to absorb moisture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard plastic lens cover or cap is simply used to protect against scratches, impact, or in the field weather conditions. It is not for any type of seal. For strictly standard plastic lens covers I would say that leaving them on or off is not going to alter the storage potential.

This question could be a bit different if you are talking about metal lens caps or even filters used for storage.