# How should I store a fungus-affected lens?

Tags: fungus

I bought a lens that has some fungus on it. Unfortunately, I can't do anything about it right now, for at least a couple of months.

How should I store it until I can deal with it properly?

Would a sealed dry container in the freezer be better than leaving it in a cupboard at room temperature?

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to remove fungus without dismantling the lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/99479/15871) and [Should lenses be stored without their caps inside a dry cabinet?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/122564/15871)

Answer (score 1):

Leave it with all of the glass exposed to sunlight on a regular (daily) basis. UV light does not allow fungi to grow. Also leave it as far from all of your other photographic equipment as you can.